# Is this Command Handler testable?

Tags: php, database, unit-testing, session, fixtures

I made some progress in understanding unit testing, but with every method I try to test, there are new questions:

```
public function handle( SendNotification $command ) {

    $DTO = $this->Assembler->build();

    $subject = sprintf(
        $command->getFirstName(),
        $command->getLastName()
    );

    $EmailComponents = new EmailComponents(
        $subject,
        $DTO->getProject()->getSettings()->getValueOf( 'recipient' ),
        $this->OptionQuery->getOption( 'business_email' ),
        $this->NotificationRenderFactory->render( 'template' ) )
    );

    $this->Mailer->send( $EmailComponents );

}
```

The `$DTO` is basically an aggregate cluster with 'project' being the aggregate root. It reads data from a PHP Session to determine the current project, and the `OptionQuery` reads data from a database. So my current understanding is that I would have to create a fixture that sets up both an aggreate, a testing database and a mock that returns something for my session object. Is that correct and if so, why would I want to put that much effort into testing a single method?

**EDIT** I the meantime, I refactored the `handle` method to make it more testable:

```
public function handle( SendNotification $command ) {

    $EmailComponents = $this->EmailComponentsAssembler->build( $command );

    $this->Mailer->setup( $EmailComponents );

    $this->Mailer->send();

}
```

The `build` method of the assembler (which is more of a factory, really) is still pretty ugly though:

```
public function build( SendNotification $command ): EmailComponentsDTO {

    $request = Request::createFromGlobals();

    $Recipient = $this->ProjectRecipientEmailQuery->execute( $request->request->get( 'destination' ) );

    if ( !\is_email( $Recipient ) ) :

        throw new \Exception( 'No email address found!' );

    endif;

    return new EmailComponentsDTO(
        TRUE,
        $Recipient,
        (array)$command->getCustomField( 'additional_recipients' ),
        $this->OptionQuery->getOption( 'email_from' ),
        $this->OptionQuery->getOption( 'email_email' ),
        (string)$this->NotificationSubject->render( $command ),
        (string)$this->NotificationRenderFactory->render( 'EmailNotification', $command ),
        $command->getPriority()
    );
}
```

But I feel concerns are now seperated a bit better.

Answer (score 2):

Unit-testing is for finding bugs in the isolated code.  But your code is dominated by interactions, for example with `Assembler`, `Mailer`, `EmailComponents` etc.  The bugs in this part of the code will lie in the interactions with the other software parts: Are you calling the right functions in the right order with the arguments in the right order with the arguments having the right kind of content?  Testing with mocks will not answer you these questions: If you have misunderstood how to call a library, the mocks you implement will reflect your own misconceptions.  Instead, you should test such code with integration testing.

The only algorithmic code in there is:

```
$subject = sprintf(
    $command->getFirstName(),
    $command->getLastName()
);
```

which even looks wrong to me, since I would expect some format string to be the first argument to `sprintf` (but I am not familiar with php).  If I am right about this being a bug, it is, strictly speaking, also an integration bug, but one which you can find with unit-testing, since you would not bother to stub `sprintf`.

Thus, a possible solution for your testing problem could be to extract the creation of the subject string into a small helper function and test that one with unit-testing, but test the rest of the functionality with integration testing.

Comment: Thanks for looking over my code. I have refactored it to make it more testable and hopefully more meaningful (see edit of original question).